# How to find a employer that allows staff to publish academic papers

Tags: job-search, student

As a Ph.D. candidate, one of the things that I am looking for, when looking for a job, is the opportunity to continue publishing academic papers related to work. I know that there are some companies whose workers publish academic papers, such as: Google, Microsoft, IBM and Yahoo. I am wondering whether there is some website that compares companies according to how academic they are. E.g, counts the number of publications per worker in each company, etc. Is there any website that publishes such information?

Comment: Possible related - http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/does-one-need-to-be-affiliated-with-a-university-to-publish-papers
Maybe your specific question might be better answered on that forum?

Comment: I'd guess that this would be better asked on one of the Stack Overflow academic sites (of the field that you work in)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it really belongs on Academia stack exchange.  However you may want to edit it to avoid merely asking for a resource recommendation (which is off topic there as well).

Comment: Companies that give this any kind of priority may boast about this on their individual websites.

Comment: Getting info interviews with current employees in technical roles might help. I found out through an alum of my PhD program that scientists at his company (in Big Pharma) are promoted on the basis of their publications at the company as much as they are promoted based on patents or other more industry-oriented metrics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If that's the particular means of getting information you are looking for - a website with a nice ranking system - I suspect you are out of luck.  I haven't yet heard of such a thing, and I'm not sure you'd actually get accurate information... or if it would really answer your question of "is this a place that is a good next step in my academic career".

Some things to think about:

- Knowing that some people have published papers from a given company is useful... but as important is - are they writing papers that are valuable in your opinion?  I've seen a lot of boring, useless academic papers (at least to me) in all sorts of fields, and so for me the motivation would be to not only look for publications but to read the writing see if they are coming from people with ideas that interest you and communication that inspires you?  Those are the great folks to work with.
- Certainly there are topic-focused sites that will give you access to academic publications... I'd actually start there and pick out recent works (2-3 years) that are interesting and follow up on the authors and their careers.
- There is certainly a type of company that is more supportive of academic research and publication than others - some companies are so protective of intellectual property that they will limit publications, or at least limit publications in certain roles.  Whenever you interview, it's worth asking about the policy and whether (A) it's allowed, (B) what the restrictions are, (C) how supported is it.  There's a contrasting corporate view that publications are good publicity, because it shows the company is smart, innovative and doing new things.
- Will you be doing the type of work that leads to good papers - if this is something you want, you really want to make sure that you're working in a role where you'll have the opportunity to develop paper-worthy ideas.  Another good topic when interviewing.

Comment: Very good answer, especially your last point. I work in industry and do quite a bit of publishing, but I'm far and wide the only one here to do so. Everyone else simply doesn't do the kind of work that leads to published articles. So whatever a metric like "number of publications per year and FTE" says, this can only be answered by talking to the specific company in an interview for a specific position.

Comment: Exactly!  In many industries there are few "prolific paper writing people" and then a bunch who don't do it for various reasons.  And I've interviewed in places where the rules where entirely undefinited because there was really nothing worth writing a paper about. :/